# Choppy bluetooth sound when another BT device connected 22.04.1

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

If the only bluetooth device that is connected are my earbuds (JLab GO Air), then sound is perfectly fine. However, once I connect my BT keyboard, my earbuds suddenly experience severe sound choppiness and lag.

What I've done:

- switched over to pipwire
- already using blueman
- tried connecting keyboard first, then tried second, same result

Earbuds also work fine if I use my 2.4G wireless keyboard.

result of `pactl info`:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 89
Tile Size: 65472
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo.monitor
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After installing blueman, open blueman then go to Adapter->Preferences->Visibility Settings, set it to "Always Visible". It should be better now, worked for me.